# How to handle event touched the editing button (UITableView)?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Please see bellow image to get my question:
[image]

Comment: Google uitableview Commiteditingstyle first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your own UITableViewCell subclass then the following methods will be called:

- `willTransitionToState:` - before cell will actually show confirmation button
- `didTransitionToState:` - after button is displayed

In both methods mask parameter will have `UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask` and `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask` flags set

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the following `UITableView` delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Then, depending on how you created your data (most likely an array), remove the object at the index of the cell.